# Mercedes start/stop system doesn't always kick in

Tags: troubleshooting, mercedes-benz

We're the (humbled) owners of a 2011 Class B Mercedes with an inbuilt ECO start/stop system. As far as I understand this is how it's supposed to work:

1. Gear in neutral.
2. Press the brake pedal *all the way*.
3. Motor turns "off".
4. Shift into first gear.
5. Motor turns back on.

The salesman remarked that the main problem people have with this system is they don't actually press the pedal all the way to the metal. However, we're experiencing that while this system just works at times, it also just doesn't work at other times. More specifically, it tends to work when leaving home and *not* to work in return trips.

The operating manual is in German since this is a used car, so I'm kind of at a loss. What's going on here?

Comment: They make the manuals in English, depending on your dealer/mech they may give you one; my mom asked and got one (a $200 book) by asking, and that was a 7 year old model at the time. I'd check my manual but the 2006 E class doesn't have this feature

Comment: my vacuum failed under stop start an i had an accident at very low speed.. the engine didnt start then..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are other factors that affect the start stop feature. I am not sure on that exact model but generally the following things will keep the car engine from shutting off:

- Coolant Temp too high, or too low
- The engine has not ran for at least two minutes
- The AC is on and not in the economy mode
- Low Vacuum
- Battery charge low
- High current draw on the 12 volt system (IE defogger, defroster, and
  windshield wipers all on at the same time)

If one of the above conditions is met it does not allow the start stop feature to work.

Comment: Pardon my asking: what does "low vacuum" mean?

Comment: @badp Vacuum is used to control things like the HVAC vents, power brakes, various valves and switches used for emission and engine controls. Vacuum is created by the engine running and there is usually a vacuum reservoir that keeps some in reserve to continue to provide vacuum in times of low engine vacuum (IE acceleration) or when the engine is off. When there is not enough vacuum to keep those things working it keeps the engine running until enough vacuum is present

Comment: I have noticed that on my 2011 Toyota Yaris, the start/stop system often goes to a mode where it doesn't work even during summer with AC off, but then again it continues working after a short amount of time. I assume there may be a system that occasionally shuts off the operation of the start/stop system to give the battery a good charge occasionally.

Comment: Stop start system always need GOOD battery, drivet seat belt MUST be fastened , close heater until engine is at normal temperature ..

Answer (score 0):

This should shed some light on the mysterious stop/start function. We bought a 2019 GLC 300 we thought the stop start wasn't functioning correct. We took it to the dealer, battery was good everything was operating correct . They added a new software. When we left it worked twice then stop working. I stayed thinking about the problem. I decided that the AC was the only variable that could prevent the function from operating. I noticed that my wife was setting her AC on here side to low 60s. Since we live in Miami setting the AC that low will prevent the stop start from engaging because the engine needs to cool the inside to the AC setting. I decided to set the AC to 77 degree on both side , sure enough the engine turn off when we came to a complete stop. Then we lowered to 75 and it continue to work. So the stop/start function will work considering everything is working good based on your outside temperature and your AC setting temperature. So I suggest try different temperature setting until stop/start engages depending where you live.